# By group processing in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a very large table with an indexed datetime field.  I want to do by group processing on the dataset by month and only output the last observation in each month.

The problem is that it doesn't contain a month field so I can't use something like this:

```
if last.month then do;
  output;
end;
```

Is there a way I can achieve this kind of behaviour without having to add a month field in a previous datastep?  The table is 50 gig compressed so I want to avoid any unnecessary steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually achieve this using 'by groupformat' against your original dataset, formatting the datetime field as 'dtmonyy5.'  As the name implies, this groups by the formatted values instead of the original.

```
data new1;
set old;
format datetime dtmonyy5.;
by groupformat datetime;
if last.datetime;
run;
```

Another method is to use Proc Summary, although this can be memory intensive, particularly against large datasets. Here is the code.

```
proc summary data=old nway;
class datetime;
format datetime dtmonyy5.;
output out=new2 (drop=_:) maxid(datetime(_all_))=;
run;
```

Just a quick note on the previous answer, the 'month' function works against date fields, not datetime, so you would need to add the datepart function to the line.

```
month = month(datepart(datetime));
```

Comment: Interesting approach. And thanks for the correction -- I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome - I had no idea you could do this!  Both solutions work great. I've accepted Keith's as it has the advantage of not needing to create a view.  If I could vote both answers up multiple times I would...

Comment: Also - if you're running proc summary on large datasets try adding the `/groupinternal` switch to any class variables that you don't need grouped on formatted values.  I've seen performance improvements in the measure of 30% from doing this.  You can use multipple `class` statments so this allows for some to use the switch and others not.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good situation to use a data view. This allows you to add variables that are created on-the-fly when the data set is processed, without creating a new physical data set.

```
data new / view=new;
 set old;
 month = month(datepart(datetime));
run;
```

If you run this, you'll see the processing time is less than a second, so you know it's not generating a new 50 GB data set. But you can just use the data view `new` with your code, as if it were a data set.

Comment: Hi Itzy - yes you're right.  The piece you are missing is that I need to also add a `by my_datetime` statement to the view in order for the following datastep to have month in the correct order for it's `by month` statement.  Feel free to update your answer with the by statement =) thanks.  And I can confirm that the index continues to be used even with the view.