# SAS: How can I filter for (multiple) entries which are closest to the last day of month (for each month)

Tags: loops, date, filter, sas

I have a large Dataset and want to filter it for all rows with date entry closest to the last day of the month, for each month. So there could be multiple entries for the day closest to the last day of month.

So for instance:
original Dataset

```
date          price       name
05-01-1995    1,2         abc
06-01-1995    1,5         def
07-01-1995    1,8         ghi
07-01-1995    1,7         mmm
04-02-1995    1,9         jkl
27-02-1995    2,1         mno
```

goal:

```
date          price       name
07-01-1995    1,8         ghi
07-01-1995    1,7         mmm
27-02-1995    2,1         mno
```

I had 2 ideas, but I am failing with implementing it within a loop (for traversing the months) in SAS.
1.idea: create new column wich indicates last day of the current month (intnx() function); then filter for all entries that are closest to the last day of its month:

```
date          price       name   last_day_of_month
05-01-1995    1,2         abc    31-01-1995
06-01-1995    1,5         def    31-01-1995
07-01-1995    1,8         ghi    31-01-1995
04-02-1995    1,9         jkl    28-02-1995
27-02-1995    2,1         mno    28-02-1995
```

2.idea: simply filter for each month the entries with highest date (using maybe max function?!)

I would be very glad if you were able to help me, as I am used to ordinary programming languages and just started with SAS for research purposes.

Comment: This question is very similar to the question [By group processing in SAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009412/by-group-processing-in-sas/9018144#9018144).

Comment: Just a note, you have to have your original dataset ordered on date descending to get it to work with the solution in the accepted answer of the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your linkt to the similar question. I just have one more question: How can I adapt the solution, so I get not only the very last entry of each month, but all entries which are closest to end of month (I edited the question. So e.g.: the last two entries of a month are on the 27th, then I want to get those two entries)

Comment: One control question, are you sure that you dont want to gruop on `name` as well?

Comment: No, that's not important in my case.

Comment: Then I would go with `proc sql`, similar to Bendys answer. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc sql` is one way to solve this kind of situation. I'll break down your original requirements with explanations in how to interpret them in `sql`.

Since you want to `group` your observations on date, you can use the `having` clause to filter on the `max` date per month.

```
data work.have;
input date DDMMYY10. price name $;
format date date9.;
datalines;
05-01-1995    1.2         abc
07-01-1995    1.8         ghi
06-01-1995    1.5         def
07-01-1995    1.7         mmm
04-02-1995    1.9         jkl
27-02-1995    2.1         mno
;

data work.want;
input date DDMMYY10. price name $;
format date date9.;
datalines;
07-01-1995    1.8         ghi
07-01-1995    1.7         mmm
27-02-1995    2.1         mno
;

proc sql ;
create table work.want as
  select *
    /*, max(date) as max_date format=date9.*/
    /*, intnx('month',date,0,'end') as monthend format=date9.*/
  from work.have
  group by intnx('month',date,0,'end')
  having max(date) = date
  order by date, name
;
```

If you uncomment the comments, the actual filters used are shown in the output table.

Comparing the the requirements against the solution:

```
proc compare base=work.want compare=work.solution;
```

results in

> NOTE: No unequal values were found. All values compared are exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

1) create a new variable periode = put(date,yymmn6.) /* gives you yyyymm*/
2) sort the table on periode and date
3) now a periode.last logic will select the record you need per periode.

Something like...

```
    data tab2;
      set your_table;
      periode = put(date,yymmn6.);
   run;

   proc sort data= tab2;
     by  periode date;
   run;

   data tab3;
    set tab2;
     by periode;
     if last.periode then output;
   run;
```

Comment: Sorry for being not specific enough in my question. I just edited it: I want not only the very last entry for each month but all entries that are closest to end of month (so e.g.: the last two entries of a month are on the 27th, then I want to get those two entries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two SAS functions called `intnx` and `intck` to do this with `proc sql`:

```
proc sql ;
create table want as
  select *, put(date,yymmn6.) as month, intck('days',date,intnx('month',date,0,'end')) as DaysToEnd 
  from have
  group by month
  having (DaysToEnd=min(DaysToEnd))
;quit ;
```

`Intnx()` adjusts dates by intervals. In the above case, the four parameters used are:

1. What size 'step' you want to add/subrate the intervals in.
2. The date that is being referenced
3. How many interval steps to make
4. How to 'round' the step (eg round it to the start/end/middle of the resultant day/week/year)

`Intck()` simply counts interval steps between two dates

This will give you all records which fall on the day closest to the end of the month

Comment: Sorry for being not specific enough in my question. I just edited it: I want not only the very last entry for each month but all entries that are closest to end of month (so e.g.: the last two entries of a month are on the 27th, then I want to get those two entries)

Comment: No problem - just added an update to amend the `proc sql` to give you more than one record

Answer (score 0):

```
Another approach is by using proc rank;

data mid;
  retain yrmth date;
  set have;
  format date yymmddn8.;
  yrmth = put(date,yymmn6.);
run;

proc sort data = mid;
  by yrmth descending date;
run;

proc rank data = mid out = want descending  ties=low;
by yrmth;
var date;
ranks rankdt;
run;

data want1;
  set want;
  where rankdt = 1;
run;
```

HTH